# Class runs when require

Tags: ruby, class, require

I have required a file with a class in it, but never created a object for required class. But when I run the 'main.rb' file the required class is started. Why ?

main.rb

```
require "./required_class.rb"

puts "This should be listed first"
```

required_class.rb

```
class Hello_World
    puts "Hello World"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ruby classes don't behave like functions, they are evaluated on execution. because of this fact your class is effectively no different from simply:

```
puts "Hello World"
```

What you're seeing is expected and if you just run in IRB:

```
> class Hello_World
>     puts "Hello World"
> end
"Hello World"
=> nil
```

To stop it from running when you `require` the file containing it you'd need to create a constructor function like so:

```
class Hello_World
    def initialize
        puts "Hello World"
    end
end
```

Now you won't see any output until you run `Hello_World.new`
If you want to be able to print your message without instantiating you could use:

```
class Hello_World
    @@hello = "Hello World"
end
```

Then you can get the message with `puts Hello_World.hello`

Answer (score 2):

Because the body of the class gets evaluated when you require it. Often you'll see class definitions return `nil` because the last thing in the class was a method definition (from 2.1 onwards `def` returns the name of the method as symbol).